# Size of HashMap not increasing

Tags: java, hashmap

I go through a loop three times and call this method each time:

```
// class variable
private HashMap<String, ffMotorskillsSession> tempMap;


tempMap = new HashMap<String, ffMotorskillsSession>();
for loop {    

     addMotorskillsSession(session);

}

private void addMotorskillsSession(ffMotorskillsSession pSession) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(pSession.period).append(":").append(pSession.section)
            .append(":").append(pSession.class_name).append(":")
            .append(pSession.semester).append(":").append(pSession.grade);
    tempMap.put(sb.toString(), pSession);
    Log.d("Size: ", String.valueOf(tempMap.size()));
}
```

Everytime I `Log` the size each time it passes thru it stays at one.

Can anyone see why?

Comment: Well presumably you're putting the same key in the map every time...

Comment: What's `sb.toString()` each time, is it the same :)?

Comment: @JonSkeet   That is proably wy! thanks!  I never use `HashMaps` before so didn't realize that.  I am used to working with `ArrayList<>`  Go ahead and mark answer

Comment: @KickingLettuce You might want to have a look at the general contract of a [`Map` (documentation link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). The primary purpose is to store a map of unique keys -> values.

Comment: @JasonC  Thanks.  I was so caught up in the Object (value) the thought about the key as completely over looked since it was variable based.

Comment: What's with the obfuscated string building??  It would be better to just use `+` in this case.

Comment: @StephenC  Hey good call.  I took this project over from someone else so it's on them!  I'll clean that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Map` stores key/value pairs, with only one value per key. So if you're calling `put` with the same key multiple times, then it will *correctly* stick to the same size, only having a single entry for that key.

Comment: @Robert: Um, you've just linked back to the same question...

Comment: Sorry, corrected